# HTACCESS problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I can't get .htaccess to work (on the server nor on xampp).

The url looks like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/new/index.php?p=category&id=1&url=cards
http://mydomain.com/new/index.php?p=product&ip=1&url=bussiness_card
```

("new" is a folder of the new version of the site on which I'm working now)

As I understand the rewrite should put it like:

```
http://mydomain.com/new/category/cards
```

No?

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(new/admin)/*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/(.*) 
# For Friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).html /new/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).html /new/index.php?p=$1&url=$2 [L,NC]
```

I have the same problem in XAMPP, settings for url rewrite are activated in http.conf but it's not working. Can anybody explain to me (or give me a step by step an very explicit tutorial) why it's not working?

Comment: Do you want the user to see `http://mydomain.com/new/category/cards` in the url or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteBase /new/` you've tried that? Do you get any 500 internal server errors, or do you get 404 when trying to access the URL?